# Parsing functions inside functions

Tags: java

I am having a problem to come up with a great algorithm to solve my parsing specific problem with Java. I am trying to parse a special language designed for a specific system.

String that I would need to parse could look like this:

```
function1(text1, function2(function3(function4(), function5())))
```

Results from this should be in a form like this:

```
1. function1()
2. function2()
3. function3()
4. function4()
5. function5()
```

Different kind of strings to be parsed:

```
function1(function2())
RESULTS: 1. function1() 2. function2()

function1(text1)
RESULTS: 1. function1()

function1(text1, function2())
RESULTS: 1. function1() 2. function2()

function1(function2())!=function3()
RESULTS: 1. function1() 2. function2() 3. function3()

1!=2
RESULTS: none
```

I've wasted a lot of time for thinking about this but I just can't figure out the simplest way to do it. Every solution gives me a feeling that there has to be a better way to do it.

Also it would be great if someone could suggest how I could collect the operators used between the functions as separate results on the way.

Comment: Depending on the level of correctness you want to reach, you could go from simply finding any identifier that is followed by an open parenthesis, to implementing a full tokeniser, parser, abstract syntax tree and paraphernalia. What do you want to do? What have you tried so far? And, as this positively *stinks* of homework, have you even read the appropriate chapter?

Comment: Well this certainly is not a homework. I am trying to ease up things at work for myself. First I tried many simple approaches like looking for first and last parenthesis until I've reached the deepest point, but it fails if the last one contains two function calls. So now I've been looking into tokenizers, parsers and lexers.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like JavaCC is suitable for this kind of task:

https://javacc.java.net/

Quick faq:
http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc1.2

Comment: I don't want to compile the code, just to get results in the way mentioned above from different kind of text strings containing "functions" like that.